# MIPS stack visualization

Tags: assembly, stack, mips

Below is a c code for a factorial function. 
I clearly understand how the recursive function works. 
but I can't visualize or don't know how to works on the MIPS stack.

[image]

MIPS CODE

[image]

My question is, 
how are we saving the recursive function (saving return address & arguments) in the stack for each step of the recursion?

I know that for each recursive function, we are saving the arguments and return address and then readjusting the **stack pointer.**

Can someone help me visualize how the process works.

Comment: You pretty much explained it. You store those two values in the stack each time a call is made. It's a stack so it's a linear block of memory. I don't know how it can be made any clearer.

Comment: Just some pictures of each recursive call would be great so I'm 100% confident about the idea

Answer (score 1):

**Premise** The stack in MIPS works just as the stack in any other architecture, so you can just Google for that.

---

Assume the stack point to an arbitrary location of memory:

```
|  xxx   |                xxx = Undefined 
|  xxx   | <- $sp
|        |
|        | | Free area, stack moves down
|        | V
```

Now just simulate a call to, say, `fact(3)`.
<sup><sub>You pasted an image of the code, so no code will be shown here. A copy-pastable code would have made this answer much clearer.</sub></sup>

Each invocation of `fact` pushes the return address and the argument, in this order.
Let's assume `fact` is at 0x1000 and that the call to `fact` is at 0x1ffc.

```
fact(3)

|  xxx   | 
|  xxx   |
| 0x2000 | Return address to caller of fact(3)
|    3   | <- $sp          Argument of fact(3) 
|        | 

fact(2) called from fact(3)

|  xxx   | 
|  xxx   |
| 0x2000 | Return address to caller of fact(3)
|    3   | Argument of fact(3)
| 0x1028 | Return address to L1+8 label
|    2   | <- $sp          Argument of fact(2)

fact(1) called from fact(2)

|  xxx   | 
|  xxx   |
| 0x2000 | Return address to caller of fact(3)
|    3   | Argument of fact(3)
| 0x1028 | Return address to L1+8 label
|    2   | Argument of fact(2)
| 0x1028 | Return address to L1+8 label
|    1   | <- $sp          Argument of fact(1)

fact(0) called from fact(1)

|  xxx   | 
|  xxx   |
| 0x2000 | Return address to caller of fact(3)
|    3   | Argument of fact(3)
| 0x1028 | Return address to L1+8 label
|    2   | Argument of fact(2)
| 0x1028 | Return address to L1+8 label
|    1   | Argument of fact(1)
| 0x1028 | Return address to L1+8 label
|    0   | <- $sp          Argument of fact(0)
```

`fact(0)` return 1 and remove two items from the stack.
`fact(0)` is a leaf invocation, i.e. the last invocation, so no other call changed `$ra`, furthermore `$a0` (the argument) is not needed, thus these two values saved on the stack are simply discarded by incrementing `$sp`.

```
Just before "jr $ra" in fact(0)

|  xxx   | 
|  xxx   |
| 0x2000 | Return address to caller of fact(3)
|    3   | Argument of fact(3)
| 0x1028 | Return address to L1+8 label
|    2   | Argument of fact(2)
| 0x1028 | Return address to L1+8 label
|    1   | <- $sp           Argument of fact(1)
```

The other returns restore the values of `$a0` and `$ra` from the stack to compute `n*fact(n-1)` and return to their caller.

```
Just before "jr $ra" in fact(1)

|  xxx   | 
|  xxx   |
| 0x2000 | Return address to caller of fact(3)
|    3   | Argument of fact(3)
| 0x1028 | Return address to L1+8 label
|    2   | <- $sp           Argument of fact(2)

Just before "jr $ra" in fact(2)

|  xxx   | 
|  xxx   |
| 0x2000 | Return address to caller of fact(3)
|    3   | <- $sp            Argument of fact(3)

Just before "jr $ra" in fact(3)

|  xxx   | 
|  xxx   | <- $sp
```

Note how the stack is returned to the original position at the end of the recursion chain.

Comment: The `xxx` values upon entry to `fact` are "undefined" from the standpoint of `fact`, but, might be more properly stated as "owned by caller" as they may have values caller put there and can't be changed. For the level 1 call to `fact`, they are the level 0's stack frame.

Comment: Thanks for the note @Craig, I intended "undefined" as "not defined in this context" as the caller (of *fact*) stack is not part of the discussion. I'm confident the OP will realise the fact you stated by themselves as soon as they will properly understand how the stack works :)